# VLC Server Webinterface failes to start

Tags: vlc

I'm trying to start my VLC Webinterface with "vlc -I http".
The Webserver starts, but there is no audio.
Here is the error message:

```
inhibit interface error: Failed to connect to the D-Bus session daemon: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
main interface error: no suitable interface module
main interface error: no suitable interface module
main libvlc error: interface "globalhotkeys.none" initialization failed
```

I tried to unistall and reinstall VLC, but it didn't work.

What does that error message mean?

Answer (score 0):

It means you're starting your VLC on a headless console, without access to X nor your DBUS session, which VLC would normally need to access the sound system.

Try specifying alsa as sound system via command line arguments, `export DISPLAY=:0` before starting VLC (if you're currently logged in a graphical user interface).

Comment: ok, now i have more errors :(
i got also:
main interface error: socket bind error (Permission denied)
cannot create socket(s) for HTTP host
error loading script /usr/lib/vlc/lua/intf/http.luac: lua/intf/http.lua:332: failed to create http host

Comment: More errors mean you get further, which is a good thing. I strongly recommend googling whichever error you get.